# Android HTTP Post returns null

Tags: android

I have a async task that continuously sends a message to a server and receives a message in return. When I test it, I let it run for a few seconds and then switch off the wifi. The app then crashes and sends a null pointer exception. Am I able to do anything in the HTTPPost or even just send a message if there is no internet instead of crashing the app?

This is my code

```
private class UpdateLoc extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            try{
                if(s.trim()!=null){
                    Log.d("HTTPRESULT",s.toString());
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String result = null;
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(Constants.UPDATE);
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(Constants.params_email,email));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(Constants.params_location,curr_location));

            try{
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8"),8);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                    stringBuilder.append(line+"\n");
                }
                result = stringBuilder.toString();

            }catch (ClientProtocolException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Run a check for internet connection before calling the task?

Comment: Would that slow the app down? I want to call this every 5 seconds.

Comment: Also as you already catch some exceptions. why don't you do the same to the NullPointerException?

Comment: How do I catch a null pointer?

Comment: I added a connection check before running the asynctask. Hopefully it wont slow down the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking for the network connection before calling the `AsyncTask`, something like:

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

=======

You can find the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html).

Comment: The thing is, this won't work in some cases right? Like if Im connected to a network but there isn't an internet connection.

Comment: It checks to see if your phone has a network connection - the `activeNetworkInfo` just tells you if your device has wifi etc connected - the only way to know if you have a proper internet connection is to get a token from the site you're trying to connect. My 3G always says connected and often has errors browsing in Chrome.